# android inapp billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

i am currently testing android inapp billing.i got code from developer site.

and i followed all the instruction given in developer site.

1)uploaded apk file as draft in market

2)created product list and published

3)Registered test account and set that account as a primary account

but when i testing all other reserved product id's working fine,but my product id purchase is not working .buy button is disabled.

but developer site they mentioned that u can simulate the purchasing process so any body can give me the suggestion
[image]

Comment: Hey I need your help. I am stuck I don't know how to implement this. it is looking very very complex would you please share your code?

Comment: Hey as your demo app shows the produt list. I had also go trough this demo app &  make the product list, uploaad apk file as draft in market But it never shows the product list to me. Did you write code for the product list,or do anything else. Help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You obviously haven't selected the payment method, that's why buy button is disabled,you should choose one option - visa card or something else.

Comment: but "select payment" button asking me to enter my credit card detail.and asking me to transfer money.that is the problem whether we cant simulate that one?

Comment: It's ok. Enter the card and pay for the item, you will be able to refund the purchase after, and google won't even get it's 30% if you're using test account.

Comment: thank u so much.i am afraid to enter my credit card detail bcoz of payment, but now i am clear and i will test further with guidance from u,once again thank u so much